# Recommend a good read on prime sieving for primes of the form $x^2 + y^2$

Tags: prime-numbers, sieve-theory

Recommend a good read on prime sieving, which can be applied to sieve primes of the form $x^2 + y^2$ (or $x^2 + ny^2$, if possible).

I actually need to find up to a certain limit numbers that are simultaneously representable as $x^2+y^2$ and $x^2+2y^2$ and $x^2+3y^2$. I know which primes can be representable in these forms, and then Eratosthenes sieve can be applied... But I thought there might be something more efficient.

Thank you!

Comment: The question as it stands is a bit vague: are you asking for a sieving method to extract all primes of the form $x^2+y^2$ from the set of all integers up to some limit? If this is the case, then just use the Eratosthenes sieve to extract all primes, and then discard those which are $\equiv 3 \pmod{4}$. The case of $x^2+ny^2$ cannot be done so simply.

Comment: I actually need to find up to a certain limit numbers that are simultaneously representable as $x^2+y^2$ and $x^2+2y^2$ and $x^2 + 3y^2$, etc.. I know which primes can be representable in these forms, and then Eratosthenes sieve can be applied... But I thought there might be something more efficient.

Comment: OK, that makes it clearer - you might like to edit that information into your question, to help others to help you. When you say you know which primes are representable in these forms, do you have a simple way to decide if a number is representable by (say) $x^2+14y^2$?

Comment: Let's stick to the case, when numbers should be representable simultaneously as $x^2+ny^2$ for $n=1\ldots3$. For these forms you can definitely say which prime powers can be factors.

Comment: What is the source of this problem?  This feels remarkably like a Project Euler or coding-contest question...

Comment: Lol, it is! It's Project Euler's #229. I've found which prime powers numbers can have. Now it seems to me I should apply some tricky sieving. Which I'm bad at. Yet I don't want the problem solved for me, that's why the problem's description is (or was) somewhat unclear...

Comment: If you are going to stick to the nice cases ($n=1, 2, 3$), then these can be described fully by congruences, so you could combine all the congruence conditions using the Chinese remainder theorem and avoid any complicated sieving, I believe.

Comment: Ok, I'll try. Thank you!